# jQuery if ID hasClass not working

Tags: jquery

I need to set a class's height if an ID has a specific class. I'm using the code below which doesn't work

```
if ($('#nav_menu').hasClass('active')){
    $('.extra').css("height","3000px");
}
else{
    $('.extra').css("height","100%");
}
```

The html of `#nav_menu` is `<li id="nav_menu">` this list item gets a class when clicked. So when it is `<li id="nav_menu" class="active">` the `.extra` class should get it's height set to 3000px.

What's wrong with my if condition? Thanks

Comment: Are you expecting this to run when someone hovers your menu, because this is only going to run once when your page loads.

Comment: @watson I did use ` $('#nav_menu').click(function(){
$('.extra').css("height","3000px");});` earlier but need the `.extra` height to reset when another `li` is clicked.

Comment: 'I need to set a class's height if an ID has a specific class.' That sounds like inefficient use of CSS :-)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.css` you can use `.height`.  Also you handle it using `.on('click',..)` handler, there is no need to check whether it hasClass or not.

**By default:**

```
.extra {
height: 100%
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#nav_menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.extra').height(3000px);    
});
```

Comment: Thanks I used a similar function but need the .extra to reset to 100% once another li link is clicked on

Comment: Then when you click the other `li` you should reset this `.extra` there.Once you click you will get class `active`  so checking class is very similar to click.  Hope you understand.